# Can't copy project to docker container - Laravel (Lumen)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile, libreoffice

I am new to `Docker` trying to Dockerize simple lumen app locally.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:8.1 as php

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY ./ /project
COPY . .

COPY --from=composer:2.4.2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

**docker-composer.yml:**

```
version: "20.10"
services:
  # PHP Service
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      target: php
      args:
        - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
      - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  # Libre Office Service
  libreoffice:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/libreoffice:latest
    container_name: libreoffice
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Everything works fine but I can't copy my project to custom directory in `libreoffice` container.

When I access `libreoffice` container with `docker exec -it libreoffice /bin/bash` I can't see `project` directory here. But in `/var/www` directory there is all directories that is in my local computer.

**You may question** why you are trying to copy your project to different directory?

Because I am running following command in `libreoffice` container:

```
docker exec libreoffice soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir "var/www/PhpstormProjects/document-converter/public/tmp" "var/www/PhpstormProjects/document-converter/public/tmp/hi.docx"
```

But in this commannd I don't want to specify my path like `var/www/PhpstormProjects/document-converter/public/tmp`.

Because when I upload it to the live server the directory will change and it will not work properly. Means each time I change project path, I will need to change path in code as well.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or another way I can do it.

Comment: `/project` is declared in the Dockerfile you use for the 'php' service. Has nothing to do with your local setup. Also you copy the same files twice: to `/project` and to `/var/www` in the php service. Doesn't really make sense

Comment: I know. But how can I copy my project to `/project` folder? In which service I have to do it? As I said I am new to docker so I need exact solution for my issue.

Comment: just add a volume ".:/project" to your libreoffice service.

Comment: Thanks. You can post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By help of [@Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11280830/mihai) I have found that:

`COPY` in the `Dockerfile` is related to `php` service as I defined at the top:

```
FROM php:8.1 as php
```

It has nothing to do with `libreoffice` service. To `COPY` my project to `libreoffice` service I need to define volume for it in `docker-compose.yml` file like:

```
# Libre Office Service
  libreoffice:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/libreoffice:latest
    container_name: libreoffice
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - ./:/project # You can define any directory you want
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
```